# Replace Google Map with image when offline

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm just wondering if there is a way to change a div that has a google map in it, to a static image when connection gets lost. The code does location tracking, so caching the map would be useless to me. I have a function that updates the map every 10 seconds (this will be used in a car with a mobile wifi system), but does so only when there is a connection. Is there a way I can change the map to an image when offline? I've tried using the visibility and display properties, but the map remains in place. The image I want to overlay is id="alt_img"

```
<div id="right_top_div" style="position:absolute; right: 0; width:50%; height:768px; z-index:10; background-color: #FFF" >
    <img id="show_more_button" src="images/show_more_button.png" style="position:absolute; left:0;top:38%; width:40px; height:150px; z-index: 12" />
    <img id="alt_img" style="position:absolute;left:0%;visibility:hidden; z-index:10" src="images/greencab_ad.png" />
    <div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color: #FFF" >
        <img style="position:absolute;left:48%;top:50%; z-index:1" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first you'll need to work out whether there is a connection or not. the rest is simply and if statement based on this result. if connected show map else show image.

Comment: There will be a connection when the program starts, but since it's using wifi in a moving vehicle the connection will drop here and there. I have the code to test if there is a connection, but I just can't get an image to cover up the map when there isn't a connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about just having the image in another div that is on top (z-index) of the map, and then you would just adjust it's visibility, not really changing the map itself (that way you wouldn't have to re-initialize the map over and over, as those would count against your map quota):

```
<div id="right_top_div" style="position:absolute; right: 0; width:50%; height:768px; z-index:10; background-color: #FFF" >
    <div id="not_connected" style="position:absolute; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:15; display:none;"><img src="image_for_no_connection.png"></div>
    <img id="show_more_button" src="images/show_more_button.png" style="position:absolute; left:0;top:38%; width:40px; height:150px; z-index: 12" />
    <img id="alt_img" style="position:absolute;left:0%;visibility:hidden; z-index:10" src="images/greencab_ad.png" />
    <div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color: #FFF" >
        <img style="position:absolute;left:48%;top:50%; z-index:1" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not getting this to work, and I tried using both display and visibility. Here is the javascript I used: if ( navigator.onLine ){
                   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(posSuccess, posError, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
                }                          else {
                        alert("hidden"); //for debugging
                        $('not_connected').style.visibility = 'visible';
                  
                }

Comment: when you use style.display, what do you set it to to reveal the image? `block`?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was in my javascript. I changed the jQuery to document.getElementById... and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can periodically save an image of the current map:

```
var google_tile = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center="+
  currentPosition.lat() + "," + currentPosition.lng()+
  "&zoom="+selectedZoom+"&size="+w+"x"+h;
// w=width of canvas/map; h = height

var canvas = document.getElementById("saved_image");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
}
imageObj.src = google_tile;
```

There you go, the canvas `saved_image` contains now a "screenshot" of your map. Put that into a function, and call it regularly. When the connection drops, display that instead.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing that, but the map uses a marker to track a vehicle. I would rather have a static image displayed when the connection goes down than have the map showing the vehicle at a previous location.

Comment: If memory serves, the link above will produce a map **without** any markers. Because if you want to add markers, you have to add extra parameters.